# enable bluetooth on startup again

Tags: bluetooth

I disabled bluetooth on startup like in answer 1 in this post [How to disable Bluetooth on startup Ubuntu 18.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1076034/how-to-disable-bluetooth-on-startup-ubuntu-18-04)

now I would like to enable bluetooth again.
I deleted the two files: bluetoothkill.sh, foo.service again in the hope my bluetooth would be working again. But even after reboot it doesn't.
When I type rskill list all it shows

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

When I open the bluetooth settings though it shows that the bluetooth is off.
It lets me click on turn bluetooth off, which changes the output of rskill list all to
`

```
  1: hci0: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: yes
```

I can toggle between bluetooth off and on as much as i want, the screen in the bluetooth settings continues showing that bluetooth is switched off

Any idea how I could get the bluetooth back to working again?

Comment: Have you tried using `sudo rfkill unblock all`? This should remove all soft-blocks. Give that a try and see if you can enable Bluetooth properly.

Comment: Hey. i had tried that already. It doesn't change anything when I do it just after  startup. When I turn the bluetooth off by clicking on it in the system settings(with no actual effect on the bluetooth functionality, it just changes the result of the rfkill list all) and type rfkill unblock all after that it'll change the result of the list all, but have no effect on what my system settings do show.